# Em golang, como fazer uma interface herdar outra interface e passar ela mesma para uma função retornar essa interface?

Tags: interface, construtor, genéricos, golang, sobrecarga

## Objetivo

Estou tentando fazer uma interface de genéricos para reutilizar funções e não escrever códigos desnecessariamente.

## Problema

Ao implementar a interface `Generic`na interface `CustomFields` consigo utilizar perfeitamente as funções de ambas as interfaces. Entretanto a situação que quero corrigir é quando vou utilizar a função de transação da interface `Generic` (`WithTx`) com as funções da interface `CustomFields`.

Devido a função `WithTx` retornar a própria interface, só é possível utilizá-la como um builder apenas com as funções da mesma interface, não sendo possível utilizar a mesma função `WithTx` com a função `DeleteAll`, por exemplo.

## Interfaces

```golang
// INTERFACE GENÉRICA
type Generic[T any] interface {
    // WithTx muda a instância do banco para uma transaction.
    WithTx(tx *gorm.DB) Genric[T]

        // Create insere um registro no banco de dados.
    Create(model *T) myerror.MyError
}

type GenericImpl[T any] struct {
    db   *gorm.DB
}

func NewGenericImpl[T any](db *gorm.DB) *GenericImpl[T] {
    return &GenericImpl[T]{db}
}

func (r GenericImpl[T]) WithTx(tx *gorm.DB) Generic[T] {
    if tx != nil {
        r.db = tx
    }

    return r
}

// Implementações da genericImpl...

// INTERFACE CAMPOS PERSONALIZADOS
type CustomField interface {
    Generic[entity.CustomField]

    DeleteAll() myerror.MyError
}

type customFieldImpl struct {
    db *gorm.DB
    GenericImpl[entity.CustomField]
}

func NewCustomField(db *gorm.DB) CustomField {
    g := NewGenericImpl[entity.CustomField](db)

    return &customFieldImpl{db, *g}
}

// Implementações da customFieldImpl...
```

## Uso

```golang
tx := co.r.Begin()

// "DeleteAll" é uma função da interface "CustomField" e como a função "WithTx" 
// retorna a interface "Generic", não tem como chamar "DeleteAll"
_ = co.r.WithTx(tx).DeleteAll()

// "WithTx" e "CreateBatch" são funções da interface "Generic", por isso funcionam como um builder
_ = co.r.WithTx(tx).CreateBatch(payload.CustomFields)
```

Comment: Creio ter ficado confusa sua questão, interfaces não são herdadas e sim implementadas.

Comment: Seria interessante você editar a sua pergunta e ler este post [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) antes de publicar, para que haja uma chance maior de outras pessoas poderem te ajudar e ser um post importante para a plataforma